# Is this pseudo class ordering non-conflicting?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I am aware that the pseudo classes must be in order in order to not conflict each other. (double 'in order' intended)

The thing is that I read that CSS reads from right to left (when finding a match), and that put me in doubt about this:

```
a{
color:blue;
text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover,a:focus{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Should it be `a:focus,a:hover` or it is good as I have it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, it shouldn't matter, as they cannot both be triggered at the same time... given that `:hover` is for link events triggered with a mouse and `:focus` is for link events triggered with a keyboard.

However, read this

> The :link and :visited pseudo-classes should generally come first.
>   Next should be :focus and :hover—they’re specified now so that they
>   override and apply to both visited and unvisited links. If :focus
>   precedes :hover, the hover effect will apply to links with keyboard
>   input focus. The :active pseudo-class should always come last, since
>   we usually want to indicate clearly any links that have been
>   activated.

From here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclasses

In this case, I think ideal would be

```
a:link{
}

a:visited{
}

a:focus, a:hover{
}

a:active{
}
```

Comment: well, I knew that. The problem was if `a:focus, a:hover` is the same as `a:focus{} + a:hover{}` or `a:hover{} + a:focus{}`?

Comment: It looks like definitely `focus` first, in order to get the most out of the pseudo class.

Comment: in what based your decision to chose one over the other?, please explain (: